# System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

I have looked through a couple of answers on this topic and didn't find an adequate answer to an issue I'm having with this error. I have a pretty similar setup in another class and there are no problems there, but here it's an issue for some reason.

```cs
public partial class DishManager : Window
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection;

    public DishManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POS_WPF1.Properties.Settings.POSdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    private void AddDish_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "if not exists (select * from Dish where Name = @Name) insert into Dish values (@DishID, @Name, @Price, @CategoryID)";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DishID", dishIDBox.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dishNameBox.Text);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", categoryComboBox.SelectedIndex);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", dishCostBox.Text);

            sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The stored information is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dish] (
    [Id]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DishID]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Price]      MONEY         NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID] INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FKCategory] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id])
);
```

Apart from the Category being linked to another table the circumstances are pretty much identical.

[Here is a what I get when the button is pressed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmr2Z.jpg)

Any advice would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the constructor of `DishManager` called?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the correct value is being assigned to your connection string string in your constructor? You might want to debug your code and check that.

Comment: Since the field `sqlConnection` is not thread safe it's either cross-thread issue or issue when the value is assigned. Check in debug what you assign in ctor and check what is the value in event-handler

Comment: Dont try to reuse connections.  Create them in the smallest scope possible, use them, then dispose of them

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Anastasia. Can you show the contents of your config file where you define the connectionstring, I suspect that it is not where you are looking for it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The `DishManager` class is inherited from window class and in the tutorials I have done that  in the ctor was not required. The sqlConnection is reused in many other classes for communicating with the SQL server so that can possibly be the issue. I do have several something like final point windows that work properly and are set up exactly the same way. The odd thing is it works fine when I do operations in my Ingredients tables and Categories tables. @PhilipSmith there is no config file for that, I just have them in their own classes for now, but I know I should set one up.

Comment: Not your question, but to avoid next one: always use explicit field list, otherwise your `insert into Dish values (...)` may fail. You should write `insert into Dish (...) values (...)` :)

Comment: Noted, thanks @Arvo. I already had some issues with it but managed to solve that. Since the fields are compulsory in this case I thought it would be fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by initializing the `SqlConnection` locally in each class member:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POSdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

I'm kind of baffled why a globally declared variable would stop working in this case.